# Display image in Excel cell base on filename

Tags: excel, image

In Excel I have a column with file names of images, and want to display the image in the cell next to the file name.
What is the easiest way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to write a macro that loops through the column of filenames and then opens the respective files.

Record a macro where you select the target cell and import the corresponding file. Then wrap a loop around it.